# Dynamic where with dynamic lookup

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to make a search that both dynamically builds the `Where` clause and dynamically looks up the field.  The `Dictionary` contains the field name as the key and its value.

This fails I believe because of the closure over `x`.  The error is:

> A cycle was detected in a linq expression

The code:

```
public List<CustomerView> Search(Dictionary<string, string> criteria)
{
    var x = (from a in base.DbContext.vCustomers
                 select a);

    foreach (var criterion in criteria)
    {
        x = x.Where(c => c.GetType().GetProperty(criterion.Key).GetValue(x).ToString() == criterion.Value);
    }
    return base.Convert<List<CustomerView>>(x.ToList());
}
```

How can I accomplish both at the same time?  I'm not looking to try to be tricky, I just want maintainable code.

Comment: You have to look at Expression Trees.

Comment: Why do you call GetValue(x) and not GetValue(c)?

Comment: @Dirk, excellent catch.  A typo on my part that got caught up in the code.

Comment: take a look  at this  link  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to construct the `Expression` object dynamically, rather than using reflection (because the query provider will not be able to translate that reflection code into SQL).  You can use this method to create the expressions:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> PropertyEquals<T>(
    string propertyName, string valueToCompare)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, propertyName),
        Expression.Constant(valueToCompare));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

The code becomes:

```
public List<CustomerView> Search(Dictionary<string, string> criteria)
{
    var x = base.DbContext.vCustomers.AsQueryable();

    foreach (var criterion in criteria)
    {
        x = x.Where(PropertyEquals<CustomerView>(
            criterion.Key, criterion.Value));
    }
    return base.Convert<List<CustomerView>>(x.ToList());
}
```

Comment: This is not a dynamic *where* clause he asks for in the title, it is a narrow approach to a wide class of problems that are better solved with expression trees and lambdas.

Comment: Lambdas can very well be translated into SQL, that's how the repository pattern is implemented.

Comment: @pid It filters the data based on the information provided in the `Dictionary`, which is exactly what the question is asking.  It is dynamic in that it is again based on that dictionary, not static filters.

Comment: @pid I said nothing about lambdas, I mentioned *reflection* being unable to be translated into SQL, because it can't.

Comment: @Servy: You are right sir, my apologies. I deleted my answer and will remove the downvote.